# C++ set and mathematical set comparison

Tags: c++

In mathematics, set comparison is based on inclusion which is not the case in c++. Is there some clean (possibly include well built library) and fast way in c++ to compare sets mathematically (solely based on inclusion)? Thank you:)

Comment: whats wrong with std::includes

Comment: in, python, when comparing two sets A,B, we just need to write if A<B then do something. While in c++, It seems more complicated?

Comment: Well, `<` is taken to mean "less-than", and in C++ this is implemented as a lexicographical comparison. I think both are arbitrary choices of those languages. The C++ choice makes more sense to me.

Comment: Yes, most things are. C++ is not Python. Use the language most appropriate for the job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The header `<algorithm>` provides `std::includes` which tells you if a sorted range is a subset of another. For example,

```
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::set<int> a{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0};
  std::set<int> b{3,4,5};

  std::cout << std::boolalpha;
  std::cout << std::includes(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), b.end()) 
            << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
true
```

Comment: oh... I see, thank you sooo much, I never came across this before:)

Comment: Your C++ book should have a chapter on STL algorithms.

Comment: Interesting that this gets down-voted. SO never ceases to surprise me.

Comment: You can also overload `operator<` to get your desired syntax.

Comment: @jxh No, you are not allowed to overload `operator<` for an `std::set`. The std library provides one, and it performs a lexicographical comparison. In the example given above, `a < b` would evaluate to `true`.

Comment: @juanchopanza: What does "not allowed" mean in this context? It seems to work for my compiler, so I am wondering if I need to file a bug.

Comment: @jxh I'm pretty sure it is undefined behaviour.

Comment: No, I think you are mistaken. What the standard defines is a template function for the `set` template. I am not proposing to redefine that (but even if you did, you could just put it in a namespace other than `std`). You can always specialize the existing template, but I was talking about creating a function specifically for `std::set<int>`.

Comment: @jxh And I think that is UB.

Comment: So you are okay with a template specialization, then?

Comment: @jxh No, not really, unless it is with a user defined type and in the cases when the standard says it is OK (e.g. `std::hash<Foo>`.)